# Haskell type and pattern matching question: extracting fields from a data type

Tags: haskell, syntax, types, pattern-matching

I'm new to Haskell and working my way through the Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours project and I came upon an instance where I wanted to get the underlying type out of a data type and I'm not sure how to do it without writing conversions for each variant in the type.
For example, in the data type

```
data LispVal = Atom String
             | List [LispVal]
             | DottedList [LispVal] LispVal
             | Number Integer
             | String String
             | Bool Bool
             | Double Double
```

I want to write something like: (I know this doesn't work)

```
extractLispVal :: LispVal -> a
extractLispVal (a val) = val
```

or even

```
extractLispVal :: LispVal -> a
extractLispVal (Double val) = val
extractLispVal (Bool val) = val
```

Is it possible to do this?
Basically I want to be able to cast back out of the LispVal if I need to use the basic type.

Thanks!
Simon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately this sort of generic matching on constructors isn't possible directly, but even if it was yours wouldn't work--the `extractLispVal` function doesn't have a well-defined type, because the type of the result depends on the value of the input. There are various kinds of advanced type-system nonsense that can do things sort of like this, but they're not really something you'd want to use here anyway.

In your case, if you're only interested in extracting particular kinds of values, or if you can convert them to a single type, you can write a function like `extractStringsAndAtoms :: LispVal -> Maybe String`, for instance.

The only way to return one of several possible types is by combining them into a data type and pattern matching on that--the generic form of this being `Either a b`, which is either `a` or `b` distinguished by constructors. You could create a data type that would permit all possible types to extract... and it would be pretty much the same as `LispVal` itself, so that's not helpful.

If you really want to work with various types outside of a `LispVal` you could also look at the `Data.Data` module, which provides some means for reflection on data types. I doubt that's really what you want, though.

---

**EDIT**: Just to expand on things a bit, here's a few examples of extraction functions you can write:

- Create single-constructor extraction functions, as in Don's first example, that assume you already know which constructor was used:

  ```
  extractAtom :: LispVal -> String
  extractAtom (Atom a) = a
  ```

  This will produce runtime errors if applied to something other than the `Atom` constructor, so be cautious with that. In many cases, though, you know by virtue of being at some point in an algorithm what you've got, so this can be used safely. A simple example would be if you've got a list of `LispVal`s that you've filtered every other constructor out of.
- Create safe single-constructor extraction functions, which serve as both a "do I have this constructor?" predicate and an "if so, give me the contents" extractor:

  ```
  extractAtom :: LispVal -> Maybe String
  extractAtom (Atom a) = Just a
  extractAtom _ = Nothing
  ```

  Note that this is more flexible than the above, even if you're confident of what constructor you have. For example, it makes defining these easy:

  ```
  isAtom :: LispVal -> Bool
  isAtom = isJust . extractAtom

  assumeAtom :: LispVal -> String
  assumeAtom x = case extractAtom x of 
                     Just a  -> a
                     Nothing -> error $ "assumeAtom applied to " ++ show x
  ```
- Use record syntax when defining the type, as in Don's second example. This is a bit of language magic, for the most part, defines a bunch of partial functions like the first `extractAtom` above and gives you a fancy syntax for constructing values. You can also reuse names if the result is the same type, e.g. for `Atom` and `String`.

  That said, the fancy syntax is more useful for records with many fields, not types with many single-field constructors, and the safe extraction functions above are generally better than ones that produce errors.
- Getting more abstract, sometimes the most convenient way is actually to have a single, all-purpose deconstruction function:

  ```
  extractLispVal :: (String -> r) -> ([LispVal] -> r) -> ([LispVal] -> LispVal -> r) 
                 -> (Integer -> r) -> (String -> r) -> (Bool -> r) -> (Double -> r)
                 -> LispVal -> r
  extractLispVal f _ _ _ _ _ _ (Atom x) = f x
  extractLispVal _ f _ _ _ _ _ (List xs) = f xs
  ...
  ```

  Yeah, it looks horrendous, I know. An example of this (on a simpler data type) in the standard libraries are the functions `maybe` and `either`, which deconstruct the types of the same names. Essentially, this is a function that reifies the pattern matching and lets you work with that more directly. It may be ugly, but you only have to write it once, and it can be useful in some situations. For instance, here's one thing you could do with the above function:

  ```
  exprToString :: ([String] -> String) -> ([String] -> String -> String) 
               -> LispVal -> String
  exprToString f g = extractLispVal id (f . map recur) 
                                    (\xs x -> g (map recur xs) $ recur x)
                                    show show show show
    where recur = exprToString f g
  ```

  ...i.e., A simple recursive pretty-printing function, parameterized by how to combine the elements of a list. You can also write `isAtom` and the like easily:

  ```
  isAtom = extractLispVal (const True) no (const no) no no no no
    where no = const False
  ```
- On the other hand, sometimes what you want to do is match one or two constructors, with nested pattern matches, and a catch-all case for the constructors you don't care about. This is exactly what pattern matching is best at, and all the above techniques would just make things far more complicated. So don't tie yourself to just one approach!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had figured, I just wanted to make sure. Haskell's type system is still a little bit of a mystery to me so I thought it might be possible that some kind of magic could happen here :)

Comment: @Simon: Well, maybe it could. If you're finding your code tedious or clumsy and were hoping to simplify it using a function like this, I'd say it's very likely that there *is* magic that could streamline it. In my experience the biggest hurdle in getting used to Haskell hasn't been doing the magic, it's been the figuring out where to put it.

Comment: @Simon: I've added some more detailed examples in an edit to give more of a feel for what options are out there.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the addendum. I'm going to steer clear of the deconstruction function for now - it seems way more complex than what I need, but the safe extractor function looks like a better version of what I had been planning to do.

Comment: @Simon: It looks more complicated than it is, and is more complicated to write than to use--but yeah, a "safe extractor" using `Maybe` is the best default approach other than direct pattern matching, I'd say.

Answer (score 6):

You can always extract the fields from your data type, either by pattern matching on *individual constructors*:

```
extractLispValDouble (Double val) = val
```

or using a record selector:

```
data LispVal = Atom { getAtom :: String }
             ...          
             | String { getString :: String }
             | Bool   { getBool :: Bool }
             | Double { getDouble :: Double }
```

However, you can't write a function that returns a String or a Bool or a Double (and whatever else) naively, since you can't write a type for that.

Comment: Thanks - I'll just be writing individual conversion functions then

Answer (score 2):

You can get more-or-less what you want by using GADTs. It gets a scary quickly, but it works  :-) I have strong doubts how far this approach will get you, though!

Here's something I whipped up quickly, with a not-quite-right (a bit too many spaces) `printLispVal` function thrown in - I wrote that to see whether you can actually use my construction. Notice that the boilerplate of extracting a basic type is in the `extractShowableLispVal` function. I think this approach will quickly run into trouble when you start doing more complicated things like trying to do arithmetic and so.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Unknown = Unknown

data LispList where
    Nil :: LispList
    Cons :: LispVal a -> LispList -> LispList

data LispVal t where
    Atom :: String -> LispVal Unknown
    List :: LispList -> LispVal Unknown
    DottedList :: LispList -> LispVal b -> LispVal Unknown
    Number :: Integer -> LispVal Integer
    String :: String -> LispVal String
    Bool   :: Bool -> LispVal Bool
    Double :: Double -> LispVal Double

data Showable s where
    Showable :: Show s => s -> Showable s

extractShowableLispVal :: LispVal a -> Maybe (Showable a)
extractShowableLispVal (Number x) = Just (Showable x)
extractShowableLispVal (String x) = Just (Showable x)
extractShowableLispVal (Bool x) = Just (Showable x)
extractShowableLispVal (Double x) = Just (Showable x)
extractShowableLispVal _ = Nothing

extractBasicLispVal :: LispVal a -> Maybe a
extractBasicLispVal x = case extractShowableLispVal x of
    Just (Showable s) -> Just s
    Nothing -> Nothing

printLispVal :: LispVal a -> IO ()
printLispVal x = case extractShowableLispVal x of    
    Just (Showable s) -> putStr (show s)
    Nothing -> case x of
        Atom a -> putStr a
        List l -> putChar '(' >> printLispListNoOpen (return ()) l
        DottedList l x -> putChar '(' >> printLispListNoOpen (putChar '.' >> printLispVal x) l

printLispListNoOpen finish = worker where
    worker Nil = finish >> putChar ')'
    worker (Cons car cdr) = printLispVal car >> putChar ' ' >> worker cdr

test = List . Cons (Atom "+") . Cons (Number 3) . Cons (String "foo") $ Nil
test2 = DottedList (Cons (Atom "+") . Cons (Number 3) . Cons (String "foo") $ Nil) test
-- printLispVal test prints out (+ 3 "foo" )
-- printLispVal test2 prints out (+ 3 "foo" .(+ 3 "foo" ))
```

Comment: Whoa, this is probably more complex than I need for this particular application, but it resulted in me looking up gadts which I didn't know about previously. Kinda neat though, thanks.

Comment: @Simon - Yes, this felt like shooting a fly with a cannon! Another keyword to search for here is 'HOAS' although I'm a bit unclear what that means exactly; the basic idea is to do some of the type checking in the type level, instead of at runtime. Lisp may not be very well-suited to this approach, however.

Comment: As a belated addendum for posterity, this is the sort of "advanced type-system nonsense" I alluded to in my answer, which I didn't feel like going into detail on because... well, just look at it, heh. There are situations where this is a useful and powerful approach, though, so I'm glad someone took up the slack and gave a demonstration!

Comment: @camccann It's not _that_ advanced, surely? :-) `LispVal` is basically the reason for inventing GADTs and `LispList` is just a list of existentially quantified `LispVal`s. Okay, it's nothing you'd see in a first course on Haskell, but it's barely registering on the Oleg scale!

Comment: It's more that (at least last I checked) there was little introductory material on practical use of GADTs, and without a solid grasp of the theoretical aspects (enough to, say, explain how `(forall a. a -> r) -> r` represents an existential type) it's easy to get stuck facing baffling and cryptic type errors. Your example barely rates a milliOleg, but the background knowledge has stuff that's at *least* 5 centiOlegs. That's my experience, at any rate, from having written simple λ-calculus evaluators both with GADTs and with types+fundeps.