# Haskell Custom Data Type

Tags: haskell

I am working on a homework assignment and we have an array of mixed elements Char and Int.

I created this custom type:

```
data Element = CharToElement Char | IntToElement Int
```

Which converts `Char`s and `Int`s into `Element`s so I can deal with them.

The issue I am having is what to do when I want to convert back?

So now that I do (head array) and that returns `Element` how do I convert that `Element` to an `Int` or `Char`.

This is for a postfix evaluator program.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

So I worked on it and this is what I have:

```
data Element = ElementConstructor (Char, Int, Bool) | IntToElement Int | CharToElement Char | NIL

extractInt (_,i,_) = i
extractChar (c,_,_) = c
extractType (_,_,b) = b

stack_push :: [Element] -> Element -> [Element]
stack_push stack element = (element:stack)

stack_pop :: [Element] -> [Element]
stack_pop stack = (tail stack)

stack_top :: [Element] -> Element
stack_top stack = (head stack)

postfix_eval eqn = (postfix_eval_rec (postfix_eval_const eqn []) [])

postfix_eval_const eqn_raw eqn_conv =
    if null eqn_raw
        then NIL
    else
        if (isNumber (head eqn_raw))
            then ElementConstructor(NIL, (head eqn_raw), True):eqn_conv
        else if (isAlpha (head eqn_raw))
            then ElementConstructor((head eqn_raw), NIL, False):eqn_conv
        postfix_eval_const (tail eqn_raw) eqn_conv


operate :: Element -> Element -> Element -> Element
operate operator_char a b = 
    if operator_char == '+'
        then IntToElement ( (extractInt a) + (extractInt b) ) 
    else if operator_char == '-'
        then IntToElement ( (extractInt b) - (extractInt a) )
    else if operator_char == '*'
        then IntToElement ( (extractInt a) * (extractInt b) )
    else if operator_char == '/'
        then IntToElement ( (extractInt b) `div` (extractInt a) )
    else
        IntToElement(0)

postfix_eval_rec :: [Element] -> [Element] -> Int
postfix_eval_rec eqn stack = 
    if null eqn
        then (extractInt (stack_top stack))
    else if ( (extractType (head eqn)) )
        then (postfix_eval_rec (tail eqn) (stack_push stack (head eqn) ) )
    else
        (postfix_eval_rec (tail stack) (stack_push (stack_pop (stack_pop stack)) (operate (head eqn) (stack_top stack) (stack_top (stack_pop stack)))))
```

The idea is that you enter something like:
    postfix_eval [1,2,3,'+',4,'+','*']
and you get an answer in the form of an Int, in this case you get 9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell - Return item from custom type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215851/haskell-return-item-from-custom-type)

Comment: (The keywords you are looking for are "pattern matching" and "case expression".)

Comment: I really don't get this concept. I looked at the possible duplicate but the person on that question is using a tuple and mashing everything together. That is not my case. Can you explain using what I gave you above in code how I would do it?

Comment: That is not a perfect duplicate indeed, but look at the second answer to that question, and how the `fsmGetQ` function there extracts a field from a `FSM` value. That is pattern matching. The only essential difference from your case is that you have two constructors (`CharToElement` and `IntToElement`), and so you will need a case expression to pattern match on both (i.e. handle both cases).

Comment: I did not try this but would this be correct: ExtractPrimitive (Char, Int) (this is appended with | at the data Element statement)

extractInt (_, i) = i
extractChar (c,_) = c. I am trying to understand what you meant first. Is this it?

Comment: No, it isn't. Please search for the keywords I suggested. To get you started, here is a better duplicate, with plenty of examples in the answers: [Haskell type and pattern matching question: extracting fields from a data type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6047522/2751851).

Comment: @ArnoldB if you also provide some examples of what you're trying to implement eventually (i.e. postfix evaluator) and how it should work with `Char` and `Int` values, maybe someone can come up with nice solution for you problem.

Comment: What representation will you use for your "either Int or Char"? (or in other words, you want to write a function `getIntOrChar :: Element -> ???`)

Comment: @Shersh, immibis I just posted my code. Please check it out. I think I am close.

Comment: @ArnoldB I didn't ask you to post your code though, I asked a question that you didn't answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to fix this. I'll only provide some general suggestions.

First of all, strive to use only total functions -- functions that never error out. In particular, `head`, `tail` are unnecessary in most idiomatic Haskell code, and should be regarded as a code smell.

Further, avoid `if`/guards that can be replaced by pattern matching. You really should get used to that, and there are [good tutorials](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching) around.

For instance, here's a first reworking of your `operate` function:

```
operate :: Element -> Element -> Element -> Element
operate (CharToElement '+') a b =
   IntToElement (extractInt a + extractInt b) 
operate (CharToElement '-') a b =
   IntToElement (extractInt a - extractInt b) 
operate (CharToElement '*') a b =
   IntToElement (extractInt a * extractInt b) 
operate (CharToElement '/') a b =
   IntToElement (extractInt a `div` extractInt b) 
operate _                   _ _ =
   IntToElement 0
```

This is far from being perfect. First, why returning `0` on error? There's no way the caller can distinguish that from an actual null result. Second, the function `extractInt` will necessarily be partial (or again return a bogus result): what if `a` is a char instead?

Ultimately, the big lie is already found at the type level:

```
operate :: Element -> Element -> Element -> Element
```

This type indeed lies: we do not always have a resulting `Element` for all inputs. We want to model errors instead. This is more honest:

```
operate :: Element -> Element -> Element -> Maybe Element
```

and can be implemented, again, by pattern matching:

```
operate :: Element -> Element -> Element -> Maybe Element
operate (CharToElement '+') (IntToElement a) (IntToElement b) =
   Just $ IntToElement $ a + b
operate (CharToElement '-') (IntToElement a) (IntToElement b) =
   Just $ IntToElement $ a - b
operate (CharToElement '*') (IntToElement a) (IntToElement b) =
   Just $ IntToElement $ a * b
operate (CharToElement '/') (IntToElement a) (IntToElement b) =
   Just $ IntToElement $ a `div` b
operate _                   _                _                =
   Nothing
```

And voila, no need for dangerous `extract` functions. When the inputs are not integers, we simply return `Nothing` since the first matches fail.

This might feel less convenient, since now we need to handle the `Maybe Element` in the rest of the code, which no longer receives a simple `Element` to work with. But this is the whole point! The rest of the code *needs* to cope with the possible errors, so the error handling must be performed there as well. The `Maybe Element` type forces us to do that.